# How do I find out what Chinese fonts are installed with my MacTeX installation?

Tags: fonts, texlive, mactex, cjk

I am using a Mac and have installed the MacTeX-2014 distribution. I'd like to try to use the CJK package with regular `pdflatex` but there is no documentation for what Chinese fonts are included with this distribution (or TeX Live that MacTeX is based on).

The MacTex directory structure is a bit of a mystery to me. How can I discover what Chinese fonts are installed with this distribution, either by looking at the files, or perhaps there is documentation available that I have not found?

Comment: There is a package `cjk-fonts` on CTAN but it is not part of TeX Live, so you would need to install it yourself. Have you considered using XeTeX or LuaTeX? Then you could use system fonts.

Comment: @cfr Why isn't `cjk-fonts` included in texlive?

Comment: I can't speak for the TeX Live team, but the licence on CTAN is listed as 'Un­known Sta­tus, No In­for­ma­tion Avail­able'. TeX Live includes only material covered by some form of free licence (e.g. GPL, LPPL, OFL etc.) Note that this related to the reason that documentation is missing for some packages, but available on CTAN: the author is unable, unwilling or whatever to provide the source.

Comment: @cfr: It is renamed [`arphic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arphic).

Comment: @LeoLiu How confusing!

Comment: So what is the solution?  I am using Linux and TexLive with CJK and it used to work but now I re-installed Linux and I forgot how I did it.  It was so complicated and I remember I wasted days on it :(

Answer (score 4):

You don't alway use the font installed with TeX Live. You can use any font you have if you use XeTeX or LuaTeX. It is preferred to use `xeCJK` package for Chinese and you don't need to worry about what fonts are installed with TeX distribution.

---

For Chinese, there are only these fonts preinstalled in TeX Live (MacTeX):

1. For pdfLaTeX (with `CJK` bundle), only Arphic fonts are provided. Say, the [`arphic` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arphic) in TeX Live.

   Two CJK font families are available for Simplified Chinese, `gbsn` and `gkai`. And two other CJK font families are available for Traditional Chinese, `bsmi` and `bkai`.

   *But do not use these fonts if you have other choices.*

   [image]

   ```
   % !TEX encoding = UTF-8
   % !TEX program = pdflatex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{CJKutf8}

   \begin{document}
   % We always use CJK package globally to prevent some bugs.
   \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}

   {\CJKfamily{gbsn}
   文鼎简报宋：中国字体}

   {\CJKfamily{gkai}
   文鼎简中楷：中国字体}

   {\CJKfamily{bsmi}
   文鼎细上海宋：中國字體}

   {\CJKfamily{bkai}
   文鼎中楷：中國字體}

   \texttt{http://www.arphic.com/cn/news/epaper/agent/201004/news-1.html}

   \clearpage\end{CJK}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. For XeLaTeX (with `xeCJK`) or LuaLaTeX (with `luatexja-fontspec`), you can use any Chinese font installed in the Mac OS X system. Anyway, there are also four Fandol fonts for Simplified Chinese installed in TeX Live. See the [`fandol` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fandol) in TeX Live.

   [image]

   ```
   % !TEX encoding = UTF-8
   % !TEX program = xelatex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xeCJK}
   \setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=FandolSong-Bold.otf]{FandolSong-Regular.otf}
   \setCJKsansfont[BoldFont=FandolHei-Bold.otf]{FandolHei-Regular.otf}
   \setCJKmonofont{FandolFang-Regular.otf}
   \newCJKfontfamily\kaiti{FandolKai-Regular.otf}

   \begin{document}

   饭朵宋体；\textbf{饭朵宋体}

   \textsf{饭朵黑体；\textbf{饭朵黑体}}

   \texttt{饭朵仿宋体}

   {\kaiti 饭朵楷体}

   {\CJKfontspec{Hiragino Sans GB W3.otf}
   冬青黑体 or any other font installed in your system.}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: It turns out that the Fandol fonts are extremely incomplete. A test section of writing turned out about 30% missing characters. I would like to avoid fonts that I might not have access to if I move the document to another computer to compile. I think I'm sticking with `bkai` for the time being. I'm not sure why people are against the arphic fonts but they look okay to me.

Comment: @ana: Fandol fonts are **Simplified Chinese** fonts. If you need Traditional Chinese, you have to use other fonts (usually commercial).

Comment: @ana: It is a bad news that there is NO free Chinese font installed with TeX distribution that is suitable for both Simplified and Traditional Chinese. You have to use other fonts in your operating system.

Comment: how can I install these fonts via TexLive?  or in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

To find out what Chinese font you have in your laptop, bring up the terminal and type in

```
fc-list :lang=zh-cn > zwzt.txt
```

The command will produce a text file named `zwzt.txt` or however you would name it, with all Chinese font listed.

If a utf8 ignorance error is reported, run the following

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: On MikTeX, the binaries have been re-named, to put them into their own namespace: it is called `miktex-fc-list` now.